# How to fastly copy only a portion of an array to another array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, sizeof

I'm writing a high-performance data structure. One problem I came across is there doesn't seem to be anyway to copy only a portion of an array to another array (preferably as quickly as possible). I also use generics, so I'm not really sure how I'd use `Buffer.BlockCopy` since it demands byte addresses and it appears to be impossible to objectively determine the size of an object. I know Buffer.BlockCopy works at a byte-level, but does it also count padding as a byte?

Example:

```
var tmo=new T[5];
var source = new T[10];
for(int i=5;i<source.Length;i++)
{
  tmp[i-5]=source[i];
}
```

How would I do this in a faster way like Array.CopyTo?

Comment: It is possible to reliably compute the size of a generic type. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=698 and http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=728

Comment: @JimMischel that won't work. The compiler can add padding which won't be reflected by Marshal.SizeOf

Comment: And that's one reason my code doesn't use `Marshal.SizeOf`. Instead, it uses the MSIL `sizeof` instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.Copy()`.

```
Array.Copy(source , 5, tmp, 0, tmp.Length);
```

Comment: Ah! Wasn't aware there was a static `Array` helper class. And here I was thinking I'd have to drop down to IL level or something